# Nested vs. flat structures in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, schema

What metrics should I use to decide whether I want to structure my document like:

`{ count: { comments: Integer, views: Integer } }`

vs.

`{ commentCount: Integer, viewCount: Integer }`

Since indexing `count.comments` vs. `commentCount` and querying on both is essentially equivalent, which structure would make sense in this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically that will depend on how many writes/reads you are going to perform over the collection, in the case of you're going to update the counts for views and comments very often I'd suggest to go with a plain approach, other downside is that I look for creating a child complex type is the level of verbosity, if creating those kind of objects are not completely required try to keep it as much simple as possible, the queries would be a lot of easier to implement in more complex scenarios.

my two cents.

Comment: What would the trade-off be compared to longer flat-field names e.g. `commentCount` and storage efficiency? Should I shorten the field name to something else in this situation to e.g. `comcnt`?

Comment: that's topic for another question, I personally haven't done any test over the length of the names, I feel that as developers we are driven to think into the less resources we consume the better but in this case I don't consider that shortening the field names will have a serious impact over the performance, remember that the readability of the code is important as well I won't be too worried about this matter as long you're bellow the Limits and Thresholds of mongoDB you'll fine